# Are there native compilers for functional programming languages

Tags: functional-programming

Joel Spolsky [praised](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/PleaseLinker.html) native-code versions of programs that have no dependencies on runtimes.

What native-code compilers are available for functional languages?

Answer (score 12):

This post is really quite unclear.  The question appears to be "Are there compilers for functional languages which can produce native executables without the need to install additional software?"

The answer, generally, is yes.  For example, [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/) has [a compiler](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) that produces native binaries.  Many other functional languages have similar compilers.

Comment: Although, Haskell uses C-- as an intermediate language (previously used plain C) so it's not a compiled language in the same vein as C itself.

Comment: @Sean: C goes through several steps too, even if it's internal. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), for example, starts with C, but before being linked into an executable is transformed into LLVM IL and then assembly. That's not all that different from Haskell, which does essentially the same thing (although perhaps with a few more steps).

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, also:

`ocamlc` is the bytecode compiler, and `ocamlopt` is the native code compiler.
`GCL` compiles Common Lisp to native binaries.

There isn't anything for F# since, for what I am aware of, .NET doesn't have a native compiler, like Joel mentions. Actually, CSML can be used to call C# from ocaml, uhh, not sure if you can compile this down to native code --it doesn't seem likely-- although the documentation alludes to it, yet it is very incomplete.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of functional languages are compiled just like any other language.

For example in Clojure:

- The [reader](http://clojure.org/reader) translates the source code text into a data structure that represents the program (an [s-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression))
- If required, macros are then applied to transform the code
- The Clojure compiler then translates the code into Java bytecode - this is the same machine-portable format used by Java, Scala and other JVM languages
- Finally, the [JIT compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) in the JVM converts the bytecode to native machine code, possibly performing various optimisations on the fly. This is the code that then gets directly executed on whatever platform it is running.

One interesting point is that all this happens dynamically, i.e. at any point during program execution you can write new source code, pass it through the reader and various compilation steps and run the new compiled native code *without* having to restart the program. This is important as it enables [interactive development at the REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) while still providing the benefits of fully compiled code.

Comment: Then, you can also ahead-of-time compile JVM bytecode to native machine code using GCJ or IKVM/Mono.

Answer (score 1):

[PLT Scheme](http://plt-scheme.org/) has got a JIT compiler.

[Stalin](http://community.schemewiki.org/?Stalin) is a Scheme compiler which does ridiculously aggressive optimisation.

All Common Lisp implementations that I know of except [CLISP](http://clisp.cons.org/) compile to native code.  (Whether one ought to consider CL a functional language depends on what is meant by the term “functional”, however.)

[MLton](http://mlton.org/) is a highly optimising compiler for Standard ML.

Functional languages can be and have for some time been compiled very effectively.  There is no difference to imperative languages in this regard.